# E10 petrol safety

Tags: safety, gasoline, ethanol

I sometimes visit Finland taking my car, though I am not living there. There's a kind of petrol marked `E10`.

Somewhere I've read that this kind of petrol can be harmful for some kind of cars (for the tubing from gas tank to the engine in particular). How can I determine whether I'm safe? Now I've got C4 Picasso, and my previous car was Chevrolet Lacetti - which, they say, was vulnerable to this petrol.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Perfectly safe to use.  Any decrease in fuel economy is negligible and there won't be any damage to any parts, even if you used up to E30.  You could encounter a check engine light as the computer tunes itself to the fuel, but I would only expect that on older vehicles running E15 or higher.

Comment: you may already be running it. Different countrys have different rules for labeling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E10 gasoline (or Petrol) is a common term for gasoline which has approximately 10% ethanol mixed in as an oxygenating agent. Most vehicles can use this as fuel without issue, especially newer vehicles. The only problem arises when fuel gets above this level into the 15%+ range, as this level of ethanol can start degrading soft parts throughout the fuel management system.

[This website](http://www.fuel-testers.com/list_e10_engine_damage.html) is fairly neutral (as far as I can tell) about the debate. Even they suggest, when used correctly, E10 should cause no adverse effects to your vehicle. They state:

> Most newer engines can run safely on E10 blends when gas is fresh and of high quality.  Some engines are not designed for use of gasahol, and even following all precautions will cause damage. (Check your owner's manual for fuel recommendations).
>
> However, E10 damage is most often due to gasoline "contamination", and would not have occurred had the E10 fuel met all ASTM quality standards.

They go on to say:

> In newer engines E10 oxygenated gasoline can be safely used with only minimal inconvenience, such as decrease in mpg and fuel efficiency.

If you stay to the larger fueling chains with a good reputation and at fuel stations which are busy, you shouldn't have an issue. Pay attention to the blend you are using as you won't want to exceed 10% to ensure you are keeping your car safe.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your car is compatible. But you should check it to be sure. Here is a web site dedicated for this purpose http://www.e10bensiini.fi/en
You can also check this information from your car manufacturer pages.
If you can't be sure, you can always use the 98 E5 petrol. The price is really close and if you are just visiting sometimes it may be the easiest way to feel safe :)